# How do I add a custom UI for deleting vertices using the SketchViewModel?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have the following setup:

```typescript
const newView = new MapView({
  container: mapDiv.current,
  map: webmap,
  center: [17.046956, 60.843549],
  scale: 15000,
})

newView.when(() => {
  const vm = new SketchViewModel({
    view: newView,

    defaultUpdateOptions: {
      tool: 'reshape',
      enableRotation: false,
      enableScaling: false,
      toggleToolOnClick: false,
      reshapeOptions: {
        shapeOperation: 'none',
      },
    },
  })
})
```

With this I can add a custom UI with buttons for undo and redo like so:

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
        sketchViewModel.undo()
    }}
>
    Undo
</Button>
```

How can I do something similar for vertex selection and deletion? I cannot find any event I can use that fires when a vertex is selected.

Comment: How do you want to select vertice to be deleted? Do you want to do vertice selection on already selected feature? Please edit your question with more detailed info about that.

Comment: Yes the user should be able to select feature and then a vertex using the mouse. When they have selected one or more vertices they should be able to click a button (that I make) that deletes those vertices